# Visual Studio: How to indent a block of code inside braces by default with Ctrl+K,D?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I want my code to look like this:

```
if (blah blah)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hey!");    
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

however with Visual Studio, every time I format my document (Ctrl+K,D) 
the code will look like this:

```
if (blah blah)
{
Console.WriteLine("Hey!");    
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The definition is align with the braces.

What can I change in Visual Studio to remedy this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you press Ctrl+K,Ctrl+D?

Comment: `Tools` - `Options` - `Text Editor` - `C#` - `Formatting` - `Indentation`: check `Indent block contents`